# How do I inject an enumerable of interface into program class in console app .net 5?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, console-application

Hi I have a service that takes 3 enumerable of interfaces injected into constructor.

I want to call the service into the program so I believe I need the instance of the 3 list of those interfaces.

If I was not injecting a collection but just the single 3 interfaces I could do :

```
    ` var Instance1 = serviceProvider.GetService<IObject1>();
      var Instance2 = serviceProvider.GetService< IObject2 >();
      var Instance3 = serviceProvider.GetService< IObject3>();
      var service = new Service(Instance1, Instance2, Instance3)`
```

however if I do :

```
var Instance1 = serviceProvider.GetService<new List<IObject1>>();
```

this cause error.

This is my service constructor more and less:

```
 public class ShiftCalculatorService : IShiftCalculatorService
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IObject1> IObject1;
        private readonly IEnumerable< IObject2 > IObject2;
        private readonly IEnumerable< IObject3 > IObject3;
        private readonly ISettings _settings;

        public ShiftCalculatorService(IEnumerable< IObject1 > IObject1, IEnumerable< IObject1 > IObject2, IEnumerable< IObject1 > IObject3, ISettings settings)
        {
            _ IObject1 = IObject1;
            IObject2 = IObject2;
            IObject3 = IObject3;
            _settings = settings;
        }
```

Any help please?

Comment: `<new List<IObject1>>` the `new` keyword doesn't belong in a type parameter.  Is that a typo?

Comment: I don’t know how to inject an ienumerable of iobject with service provider gives error indeed @FelixCastor

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the IOC container `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` then you can resolve all instances of type `<T>` using `GetServices<T>` from an `IServiceProvider` e.g. `GetServices<IObject1>` this will return an `IEnumerable<IObject1>` i.e. all registered objects that are of type `IObject1`.